# What is the best way to allow users to search for items

Tags: python, mysql, search

I have a search feature in my application which allows users to search for products. Currently the query is

`select * from products where title like '%search_term%'`

This was a quick and hacky way of implementing this. I now want to improve this and wondering how I can do this.

**Three short examples**

1. Being able to search for plurals.

My title for the product might be `Golden Delicious Apple` then if a users searches for `apples`. Because of the plural the row will not get returned.

2. When some words could be one/two words

My title for the product might be `Lemon Cupcakes` but then if  a user searches `cup cakes`

3. If a user searches `apples and lemons` then should i return both rows in example 1 and 2 or should I return nothing? What is considered best practice.

FYI I am using python and peewee. I can think of ideas how to do this but it all gets very complicated very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, depending on what database you are using, you have a couple options.

SQLite has a very good full-text search extension that supports stemming (normalizes plural forms, etc). Peewee has rich support for the SQLite FTS:

- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#FTSModel
- http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-sqlite-full-text-search-with-python/

Postgresql has full-text as well via the `tsvector` data type. Peewee also supports this:

- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#TSVectorField
- Good post on postgresql search: http://blog.lostpropertyhq.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/

Finally, MySQL also supports full-text search, though I have not experimented with it using Peewee I'm pretty sure it should work out of the box:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

---

Regarding question 2, "cup cakes" -> "cupcakes", I'm not sure what the best solution is going to be in that case.

WIth question 3, I know SQLite will correctly handle boolean expressions in queries, e.g. "apples AND lemons" will match documents containing both, whereas "apples OR lemons" will match documents containing one or the other. I imagine postgres and mysql do the same.